# send a file as httprequest c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest

Hi i need to send the file name and a file as parameters in http post method  i used following code as

```
string reponseAsString = "";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];


    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    };
    string fileToUpload = filepath;
    FileStream rdr = new FileStream(fileToUpload, FileMode.Open);
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); //Given URI is exists
    req.Method = "POST";
    req.ContentLength = rdr.Length;
    req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
    Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    Console.WriteLine(rdr.Length);
    byte[] inData = new byte[rdr.Length];

    // Get data from upload file to inData 
    int bytesRead = rdr.Read(inData, 0, (int)rdr.Length);

    // put data into request stream
    reqStream.Write(inData, 0, (int)rdr.Length);
    rdr.Close();

    // req.GetResponse();
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    string tempString = null;
    int count = 0;

    do
    {
        count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        if (count != 0)
        {
            tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);
            sb.Append(tempString);

        }
    }

    while (count > 0);


    reponseAsString = sb.ToString();
    reqStream.Close();
}
```

Here i just send the url and file path with file name as request but required response does not obtained.. but when it run through advanced client it give response in c# .net4  framework

Waiting for your sugessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) request encoding. I guess that's what your server expects. So:

```
string fileToUpload = @"c:\work\somefile.jpg";
string url = "http://foo.com/upload";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] result = client.UploadFile(url, fileToUpload);
    string responseAsString = Encoding.Default.GetString(result);
}
```

But this is limited to a single file only. If you needed to upload more than one file or add other simple parameters to the POST body you might need to manually do that. I've [blogged about a sample class](http://www.bratched.com/en/component/content/article/69-uploading-multiple-files-with-c.html) that could be used in this case.

Comment: Ya thanks but i need to set another field variable as formfield in it how can i do it

Comment: Read my blog post: http://www.bratched.com/en/component/content/article/69-uploading-multiple-files-with-c.html